# SQLBase > Show Data

Tags: sqlbase

i tried to get access to a existing database to show the data. With the SQLBase Command Center i can connect to the database and got the tables. A right click to a tablename > "Show Data" brings only an error. "Encountered an improper argument."

How can I have a look to the data?
Should/Can I use a different software from "Gupta Team Developer 6.3"?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can query the data easily using Gupta SQLTalk ( SQLTalk.exe ) which should be in the same folder as Command Centre .   If not , it'll be there somewhere .
The syntax for your query is :

```
set server <servername>
/
connect <databasename> sysadm/sysadm
/
set isolation RC3
/
select * from <tableowner.tablename>
/
disconnect all
/
```